# Was Nobunaga the founder of 3 lines of riflemen formation?

Tags: japan, medieval-japan

During [Battle of Nagashino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Nagashino), Oda Nobunaga ordered his riflemen to make three lines and shoot in a certain order, that is the first line will shoot, followed by the second line. While the second line shoots, the first line will begin refilling their gun. By the time the third line finished shooting, the first line would be ready to shoot again.

This kind of formation enables his riflemen to shoot continuously. At that time, the way to fight riflemen was to let them shoot and then cut them down when they are refilling their gun. By having his riflemen shooting continuously, he successfully annihilated the Takeda cavalry.

Was Nobunaga the inventor of this formation? Or did he only made it famous after using it to great success? If so, then who was the inventor?

Comment: Rifles did not exist at this time...

Comment: Oh, you know what I mean. It's that aquebus/arquebus/arquebusher...the thing that is darn hard to pronounce, predecessor to modern day rifles.

Comment: @StuartAllan you're possibly being a bit picky there?

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify that you meant firearms vice rifles.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably fair to say that Nobunaga was the founder of the three line formation *in Japan.* That is, it's quite possible that he discovered it independently of European commanders. That's more plausible than to believe that the information "traveled" from Europe to Japan or vice versa, (given the communications of the time).

By 1575, arquebuses had been used in Europe for nearly a century, and sophisticated tactics had been developed half a century or more earlier.

Comment: Citing specific references would help to improve the answer. I did a Google search to find out how first used volley fire by rank, and have been unable to pin down the inventor(s) of this tactic.

Comment: @njuffa: I tried that myself without success. My answer is based on "common sense," about the dissemination of information, and the fact that after the 1525 battle of Pavia, cavalry tried to avoid arequebusier formations until the innovation tactics of Gustav Adolfus of Sweden a century later.

Comment: I see various statements suggesting that the origin of volley fire by rank can be found in the military reforms of Maurice of Orange (Nassau). For example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurice,_Prince_of_Orange): "One major contribution was the introduction of volley fire, which enabled soldiers to compensate for the inaccuracy of their weapons by firing in a large group. It was first used in European combat at the battle of Nieuwpoort in 1600"

Comment: @njuffa: I can make the case that both Nobunaga and Maurice made their discoveries independently, that neither learned from the other. That's more plausible than to believe that the information "traveled" (given the communications of the time).

Comment: Independent discovery is entirely possible and in fact seem likely; I did not mean to imply otherwise. From what I can gather, Maurice of Nassau ideas were partially inspired by Roman battle formations, and in 1600 the Dutch had not yet taken over trade with Japan from the Portuguese, likely limiting dispersal of Japanese knowledge to the Low Countries. Apparently the "Dutch system" was adopted rather quickly, as I found a passing reference to Swedish troops using a similar volley tactic during the Thirty Year's War, except that they rotated two ranks at a time instead of just one as the Dutch

Comment: Note - volley fire is not quite the same thing as firing by rank (which is what Nobunaga implemented). And volley fire was used at [Agincourt in 1415](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volley_fire#History) to devastating effect.

Comment: While I have not found any comprehensive treatment of the Dutch tactics introduced by Maurice of Nassau, the various bits and pieces of information I could find taken together indicate that they indeed represented *continuous volley fire* from arquebusiers by means of *rotating ranks*. Agincourt does not seem relevant here, as the question at hand is about volley fire by rank of *firearms*?

Comment: @njuffa firearm question notwithstanding, I also don't fully understand why agincourt archers *needed* to do volley fire since they could shot and reload faster than they could swap ranks. That link is less than informative. I see the point with early firearms and crossbows, but not long bows.

Answer (score 0):

History did show that Oda Nobunaga had contact with Europeans and even traded with them for prototype rifles. That being said, it was a possiblity he learnt somethings from the Europeans therefore he could have used what tactics the Europeans used on the battlefield and changed it as the situation required.

Comment: This would be improved if you included the source for "History did show...".

Comment: the book "christian century in japan" tells that Nobunaga often received and talked with European ship captains, and often in a drunken state. Even if somebody did not want to tell all secrets, one can easily imagine Nobunaga saying "so captain, while we fetch the next cup, tell me again about that old battle exploit of yours... that one where the arquebusiers where disposed in lines... ". Nobunaga certainly was shrewd enough to pull something like this. But we will never know for certain.